# Interpret byte array of an image

Tags: python, c++, arrays, python-imaging-library

What is stored in the byte array of an image? 
I was working on a project in which it was needed to interpret what is stored in the byte array of an image.
How do we interpret the elements of the byte array?

Note:
Following is the code in python to generate the byte array

```
from array import array
f = open("temp.jpg", "rb")
bytes = bytearray(f.read())
```

Comment: How did your program construct the byte array? Did you read it from a disc file? Did you use a library to create it? Was it passed to you by some outside agent?

Comment: @Robᵩ I have made an edit to the question

Comment: Interpreting the bytes of a JPEG file is not an easy problem, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Comment: A JPEG is not a byte array. Even if you had a byte array, you would need to find the definition of the format it's in to see how it should be interpreted. (Outside of movies and TV shows, there's no universal image representation.)

Comment: I'm guessing what you _actually_ want here is some kind of array of pixel values, not just an array of the bytes that make up the JFIF headers and compressed image. If you want that, you need to ask for it explicitly, by using a third-party library like [PIL/Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this with python-imaging-library, but you don't mention it anywhere in your question, and you aren't using it.

I strongly suspect that you actually *want* to be using it. You're not interested in the array of bytes that make up the JFIF header, compressed image data, EXIF segment, etc.; you want an array of *pixel values*.

So, first you have to install the Python imaging library. The modern version is named [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/), and the docs have completely installation instructions, but often it's just `pip install pillow`.

And now, you can use it in your script:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.open("temp.jpg")
>>> img.mode
'RGB'
>>> img.getpixel((0, 0))
(3, 148, 231)
```

An [`Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#the-image-class) object is sort of array-like already. The `mode` lets me know that this is an 8-bit RGB image, so each pixel will have 3 values—red, green, and blue intensities from 0 to 255. And the `getpixel((0, 0))` returns me the red, green, and blue values for the top-left pixel.

If you really want a flat array, you can go that too:

```
>>> img.getdata()[0]
(3, 148, 231)
```

Or, if you want a flat array of bytes (alternating red-blue-green-red-blue-green) instead of tuples:

```
>>> img.getbytes()[0]
3
```